# Slash commands and embed issues

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

I want to make a "help" command using new slash commands feature. Also I want embed message to be hidden, so only message author can see it:

```
@slash.slash(name='help', description='Help command', guild_ids=guild_ids)
@commands.has_role(804318858873536522)
async def help(ctx):
    embed=discord.Embed(title='Help', description='Heres the help', colour=discord.Colour.blue())
    await ctx.send(embed=embed, hidden=True)
```

When I am executing this command, I get this error:

```
discord.errors.HTTPException: 400 Bad Request (error code: 50006): Cannot send an empty message
```

If I remove "hidden" parameter, It works fine. But as I said, I want only the author can see this message. So is there any way for sending embeds like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like a bug. Sending an embed works on its own and `hidden=True` works with `content='...'`. If its possible change your embed to content.

Btw sorry for putting this as an answer I don't have enough reputation to comment.